# Error Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 7.4

Tags: php

I have a code like this:

```
// load the file
self::$_list = array();
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($handle);
    if (null != $line && count($line)!=2) continue;
    self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
}
fclose($handle);
```

But when I test, I got an error like this:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

The error refers to the script `self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);`.

Comment: Sorry, but using of array() is deprecated on 7.4?

Comment: nope, its fine. no mention of deprecation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 3):

as you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv) in the `Return` section:

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.

So the problem is `$line[0]` when you reach the end of file, because `$line` is `false`.

Please consider having a look at the examples below on that page, and use those examples as "guide" to rewrite your function, or at lease add to the middle `if` something to check that condition, like:

```
if ( null != $line && count($line) != 2 || $line === false ) continue;
```